# Dagger 2.10 add abstract module

Tags: android, dagger-2

I'm doing what Jeff Bowman described at [Dagger 2.10 Android subcomponents and builders](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43371863/dagger-2-10-android-subcomponents-and-builders) and it works perfectly fine.
Now I want to add abstract module with only @Binds
How can I do this?

After I override seedInstance my activity is not visible inside that abstract module so I probably should add something to seedInstance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you your module is an abstract class or interface, or it has a public parameterless constructor, you can just add it to your module list without supplying an instance and everything should work just fine. This means:

```
@Subcomponent(modules = {YourAbstractModule.class /*, ... */})
public interface YourActivitySubcomponent extends AndroidInjector<YourActivity> {
```

or using [@ContributesAndroidInjector](https://github.com/google/dagger/blob/master/java/dagger/android/ContributesAndroidInjector.java):

```
@ContributesAndroidInjector(modules = {YourAbstractModule.class /*, ... */})
@YourScope
abstract YourActivity bindYourActivityInjector();
```

Comment: I'm getting: Error:(8, 8) error: [dagger.android.AndroidInjector.inject(T)] com.rachapps.testapp.activity.MainActivity cannot be provided without an \@Inject constructor or from an \@Provides-annotated method. This type supports members injection but cannot be implicitly provided.
com.rachapps.testapp.activity.MainActivity ...

Comment: By [overriding `seedInstance`](https://github.com/RadoslawChmielewski/TempRep/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/rachapps/testapp/activity/MainSubComponent.java#L20), Dagger no longer counts it as `@BindsInstance`, so MainActivity isn't available to be injected in your graph. You're getting that message because your binding in MainModule looks to Dagger like you might be asking it to create a MainActivity for you, which it can't do. You'll need to make it available through a module, or by defining a different `@BindsInterface abstract` method.

Comment: Thanks for your help!